# HTML5 Audio currentTime in IOS

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

i want to play a sound, and in some cases i am changing the current time, but it is not working fine rarely times in IOS (it starts from zero sec or continue when i change the current time!)

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, very helpful. http://remysharp.com/2010/12/23/audio-sprites/

I ran this, to see if it could play:

```
    try {
                audio.pause();
                audio.currentTime = $( "#sliderOfTrack"+trackid).slider( "values", 0);
            } catch (e) {
              // what now?
            }
```